# Can I use some maven plugin (shade?) to generate a jar replacing some classes of another artifact?

Tags: java, git, maven, hystrix, maven-shade-plugin

My use case is that we are using an open source library as a dependency (namely Hystrix) and the team has found and solved a bug in it.

A pull request in the original repo was filed, but the library is out of maintenance and not accepting pull requests at this time.

We'd like to locally generate a new version of this library correcting the bug for internal use, but we don't want to copy (fork) all the library sources. We'd like to host in our git project just the two classes that we have changed because of the bug, but still be able to re-generate its artifact. That is, we want a new artifact, containing all the original files except for the two changed classes, which would be our own versions.

The main reason for not hosting the whole fork in our git is that then, due to team policies, we'd have to implement metrics (quality, tests, static code analysis, etc.) for the whole project, and not just the changed classes, and we don't want to do that.

I'm not sure if maven shade plugin could help with this use case, I've browsed it's documentation, but it's not clear if this would be supported...

Could someone point to some example or tutorial or suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: Your argument with the team metrics is not very convincing. Your way of building the project looks just like circumventing company policy. Wouldn't it be better to talk to your boss if this project may be an exception regarding metrics.

Comment: Yup, @JFabianMeier company policy sometimes is complicated... and here it's not the same for external libraries (that get CVE checked and that) and for internal code (with stronger controls) If it was as simple as a conversation with my boss, it would have taken less time than writing this post :-)
The idea behind all this is that we would like to support and keep track just of our changes and contributions to the project, which are really minimal. Also, this has to be done in our private repo (to link with our ALM) so, in the end, for us, all those unmodified sources are just noise and clutte